# read property from external file - Maven

Tags: maven, maven-2

I had to read property shared by a multiple maven project, for this purpose i try to use properties-maven-plugin like :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
                <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>conf.properties</file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>${nexusurl}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
</project>
```

and the file conf.properties contains :

```
 nexusurl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
```

the problem is that when using mvn deploy, the property nexusurl is not resolved, and the error trace resulted is :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
(default- deploy) on project parent: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector 
available to access repository snapshots (${nexusurl}) of type default using the 
available  factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute
goal   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on 
project  parent: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to 
access repository snapshots (${nexusurl}) of type default using the available
factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

I had tried to change the execution phase of the plugin (validate, install , deploy), changing the verion of the plugin to 1.0-alpha-2, but te problem persist.

I will be thankful of any aid.
Thanks,

Comment: your conf.properties seem to be ignored. How do you refer to? also what happens if you run `mvn deploy -Dnexusurl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots`?

Comment: no, the properties file is not ignored, the problem is what describing by the answer of carlspring, Values in the <properties> section are assigned when the POM is initially loaded. The properties-maven-plugin only affects plugin executions that come after the point where the properties were loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the pom.xml is read and inteporlated with properties much earlier than your plugin loads. You can use the plugin for values within your build -- for example between plugins, but what you're trying to do will not work like that.

Comment: could you have a proposition to pass the properties by another way or plugin ?

Comment: A plugin will not work for your case. The way Maven interpolates the properties into the loaded POM Model is what matters. In order for that to work, you must pass in the variable through the command-line (and I can hardly see any benefit to doing it that way). You need to keep the `<distributionManagement/>` URL hard coded for portability's sake.

Comment: It makes sense to have certain things as properties, but this one isn't quite among them.

Comment: Put the `<distributionManagement/>` in a parent POM file. Then extend it. This will let you have one central place for this setting. Much easier for maintenance and pretty close to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for the response, as solution we can put the distribution management in a parent POM for all the projects, this can facilate the maintenance of the list of hard coded properties, or to put the list of properties in a properties sectionunder settings.xml of maven